# Google App Engine - PHP - Mail not Working

Tags: google-app-engine, php-7.2

I'm trying to send an email via PHP on GAE.

I use the code from here: [cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/mail](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/mail/sending-receiving-with-mail-api)
And a very minimal `app.yaml` that looks like so:

```
runtime: php72
handlers:
- url: .*
  secure: always
  script: auto
```

I get an error in app engine logs:

```
[ERROR 0 /index.php] PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught google\appengine\runtime\RPCFailedError: Remote implementation for mail.Send failed in /srv/vendor/google/appengine-php-sdk/google/appengine/runtime/VmApiProxy.php:179 Stack trace: #0 /srv/vendor/google/appengine-php-sdk/google/appengine/runtime/ApiProxy.php(40): google\appengine\runtime\VmApiProxy->makeSyncCall('mail', 'Send', Object(google\appengine\MailMessage), Object(google\appengine\base\VoidProto), 60) #1 /srv/vendor/google/appengine-php-sdk/google/appengine/api/mail/Message.php(146): google\appengine\runtime\ApiProxy::makeSyncCall('mail', 'Send', Object(google\appengine\MailMessage), Object(google\appengine\base\VoidProto)) #2 /srv/source/contactForm.php(188): google\appengine\api\mail\Message->send()
```

When using regular PHP `mail` function, it also fails.

On local dev env for GAE PHP it also crashes with the following error:

```
Uncaught google\appengine\runtime\RPCFailedError: Remote implementation for mail.Send failed in /home/dima/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/php/sdk/google/appengine/runtime/RemoteApiProxy.php:92
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution to this?

Comment: I'm also wondering about a solution for this.  I'm running into the same problem.